# Writing a compare function for a structure for qsort?

Tags: c, genetic-algorithm, qsort

I'm having trouble writing a compare function for `qsort` function in C. This is what I currently have:

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(Individual*)a->fitness - *(Individual*)b->fitness);
}
```

I know how the compare function works but I don't understand how to reference an integer value within my structure called `Individual`. Here is the structure of the Individual.

```
typedef struct {
    PPM_IMAGE image;
    double fitness;
} Individual;
```

I want to compare the fitness values within the structure.

Comment: @kiner_shah Though the linked compare is correct for some types of floating point compare, it doesn't apply here.

Comment: @kiner_shah You provided a link to a compare function which isn't relevant for this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part

```
*(Individual*)a->fitness
```

is wrong. You try to access `fitness` using `->` but at the same time you dereference the pointer using `*`. You can't do both!

Here are two solutions.

Solution A: Dereference using `*` and access `fitness` using `.`

```
(*(Individual*)a).fitness
```

Solution B: Access `fitness` using `->`

```
((Individual*)a)->fitness
```

Both solutions also requires a cast from `void*` to `Individual*`.

The same apply for variable `b`

If you are a beginner in C I'll recommend that you avoid using compact statements where multiple things happens. Instead split the compact statement into a number of individual statements. That will make the code easier to understand and debug. Like:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b){
    Individual* pA = a;
    Individual* pB = b;
    double fitnessA = pA->fitness;
    double fitnessB = pB->fitness;
    return fitnessA - fitnessB;
}
```

You don't need to worry about performance. The compiler will optimize the code to be just as efficient as the single statement code.

That said - as spotted by @chqrlie - **notice that the compare code is wrong!**

The function returns an integer but `fitnessA - fitnessB` is a double that will be converted to an integer. So `0.1 - 0.0` will end up returning `0` - which is not what you want.

You can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53466034/4386427 from @chqrlie for further details.

The code can also be changed like:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b){
    Individual* pA = a;
    Individual* pB = b;
    double fitnessA = pA->fitness;
    double fitnessB = pB->fitness;
    if (fitnessA > fitnessB) return 1;
    if (fitnessA < fitnessB) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you call `qsort` with an array of `Individual` structures, you should cast the arguments received by the compare function as pointers to `Individual` structures, preferably `const Individual *` to avoid warnings.

You can then compare the `fitness` members and return an ordering value. Note that you cannot just return the difference of the values as these may be non integral and the difference may even overflow the range of type `int`.

Here is a classic way to do this:

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const Individual *aa = a;
    const Individual *bb = b;
    /* return -1, 0 or 1 depending on the comparison results */
    return (aa->fitness > bb->fitness) - (aa->fitness < bb->fitness);
}
```